# unable to import the module in react App getting : unexpected token import

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, babeljs

Okay, I am pretty new to the react-node-express trio. But I will try my best to explain the issue. I have a library(module/library) that was made in by someone. I am trying to import some function from that module in to my react app as -

```
import {some_module} from 'some_library';
```

Now, that module is a standalone project that exports this function, there in that project they have - import reference to some local file to which my import gives an error while loading that :

```
import * as Util from './util.js';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

my package.json have following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@bbmx/utilities": "^1.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "config": "^3.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-artifactory-artifact": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "script-loader": "0.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "^10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-config-utils": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.6.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
```

and have the .babelrc file with following config.

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime","@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties","@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

with web-pack.config as :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { getIfUtils } = require('webpack-config-utils');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { ifProduction } = getIfUtils(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development');
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const pkg = require('./package.json');

module.exports = [
    {
        name: 'client',
        entry: {
            client: ['./client', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client'],
            bundle: './client/bundle.js'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist/client/${pkg.version}`),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: `/${pkg.version}`
        },
        devtool: ifProduction('nosources-source-map', 'source-map'),
        resolve: {
            modules: [path.resolve('./client'), path.resolve('./node_modules')]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /fp-clientlib-v3.js/,
                    use: ['script-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        'less-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.png/,
                    loader:
                        'file-loader?limit=150000&mimetype=image/png&name=images/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.jpg/,
                    loader:
                        'file-loader?limit=150000&mimetype=image/jpeg&name=images/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.gif/,
                    loader:
                        'file-loader?limit=150000&mimetype=image/gif&name=images/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ico/,
                    loader:
                        'file-loader?limit=150000&mimetype=image/ico&name=images/[name].[ext]'
                }
            ]
        },
        mode,
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
        ]
    }
```

Can someone help me out as why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Node JS currently doesn't support ES6 imports. [Enable ES6 imports](https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/) in node js provides a solution to this issue. I have tired this and it worked for me.
Run the command:

```
npm install babel-register babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

Now you need to create a new file(config.js) and add the following code to it.

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: [ 'env' ]
})
// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require('./your_server_file.js')
```

Now you can write import statements without getting any errors.

Hope this helps.

You need to run the new file which you created with above code. In my case it was config.js. So i have to run:

```
node config.js
```

OR

I found one easy solution to this issue.

Create .babelrc file in the root of your project.

Add following(and any other babel presets you need, can be added in this file):

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Install babel-preset-env using command npm install babel-preset-env --save, and then install babel-cli using command npm install babel-cli -g --save

Now, go to the folder where your server or index file exists and run using: babel-node fileName.js

Or you can run using npm start by adding following code to your package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js"
}
```

Comment: Do i also need to put the entry to that config-file somewhere?

Comment: Also check .babelrc file, and it should contain something like this:

{
  "presets": ["es2015-node5", "stage-3"],
  "plugins": []
}

Comment: I have checked this... unfortunately no luck. is there anything else?

Comment: You can also enable ECMAScript Modules support by adding --experimental-modules argument to Node. But please be aware that their support is still experimental and it is not recommended to use them in production environments. In your case, you'll need to edit the package.json file of your project and replace start script command to:

`node --experimental-modules ./server.js `      Can you please try this?

Comment: Okay, i am not sure that it would help as I do have the babel-register initiated in the server.js for me and now, that I made some progress but hit another dead end, I added the amd moduler to env preset in babelrc file but now there is another error that define is not defined, coming from another module imported by the module, that I am trying to import.